# Do we need the CRACO module in the new tailwindcss version 3?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css

As I updated **tailwindcss** to version 3, I was following an old tutorial for the use of tailwindcss on frameworks like react when I realised that the teacher was creating and setting up their own **craco.config.js** file.

When I checked the Documentation for the new tailwind version, It seemed like the **CRACO** set up step has been completely forgotten.

So my question is, Do we really need **CRACO** in **tailwind 3** ?

Answer (score 1):

Tailwindcss v3 only supports Postcss8 and only create-react-app v5 supports Postcss8 for now. So you need to upgrade the create-react-app to v5. No need for craco in create-react-app v5 as well

First make sure to checkout to different branch or push your code to github before migrating, just for safety.

1.First run npm uninstall @craco/craco autoprefixer postcss tailwindcss
Delete the craco.config.js file
Delete the tailwind.config.js
Now just follow the offical [tailwindcss docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

2. Run npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
3. npx tailwindcss init -p
   copy paste the tailwind.config.js file from tailwindcss docs
4. npm install react-scripts@latest
5. Now npm start

Later paste your previous tailwind.config theme in the new tailwind.config.js file.

The order of steps may or may not matter but following this steps worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those who looking for approach to get both Craco and Tailwind CSS 3 working (e.g. if you have path aliases configured with Craco and don't want to roll-back to react-scripts or eject your project), the steps are following:

- Update your react-scripts to the latest version: `npm install react-scripts@latest`
- Both postcss and autoprefixer are dependencies of react-scripts, no need to install them separately.
- Edit your `craco.config.js` and add following lines to it:

```
    module.exports = {
        ...
        style: {
            postcss: {
              mode: 'file',
            },
        },
    };
```

- Create postcss.config.js with the following content:

```
    module.exports = {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      }
    }
```

- Create tailwind.config.js with the following content (or follow official docs and check for react example):

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
      content: [
        "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      ],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
```

Add `@tailwind` directives into your css file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```